# In SQL Server, how to find Line number in Trigger where error occurred?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table named **ph** which has one trigger named **t_ph_audit**. I am running a process which inserts & updates lot of rows in **ph** table. During the run of the process, I got an error message from the trigger:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure t_ph_audit, Line
>   840 
> String or binary data would be truncated. 
> The statement has been
>   terminated.

How can I find out exactly the Line 840 of this trigger where this error is happening?

There are couple of ways I can open the trigger:

1. In `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, I can right-click on
   that Trigger to open the right-click menu and then click on `Modify`
   option.
2. In `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, I can right-click on
   that Trigger to open the right-click menu and then click on `Script
   Trigger as --> CREATE TO --> New Query Editor window` option.
3. In `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, I can right-click on
   that Trigger to open the right-click menu and then click on `Script
   Trigger as --> ALTER TO --> New Query Editor window` option.
4. In `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`, I can right-click on
   that Trigger to open the right-click menu and then click on `Script
   Trigger as --> DROP And CREATE To --> New Query Editor window`
   option.

Which option should I use to open the Trigger so that the Line Number in the Trigger is exactly where the error occurred?

Answer (score 1):

There is no place default with the number of line it will appear, you can make apear on Superior Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> TransactSQL -> General, and then mark the option Line Numbers is the only whay to make apear.

Also you can put a log in your trigger to make a 'debug' manualy.

Hope that helps.